# Add prompt backround color iTerm

Tags: iterm2

Here is what I have now, it's hard to distinguish between the command, output, and the username-prompt.

Is there any easy way (without installin "oh-my-zsh") to add a colored background to the command prompt so I could scroll back and see the prompt commands vs output?
[image]

Or at least something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add under ~/.zshrc

```
PS1='%(?.%F{21}.%F{21})%n@%m:%~%# %f'
```

[image]

See more reference under ps1 for zshrc